# wp_query and get_posts return blank page

Tags: php

i am trying to display contents of a posttype when he storename is "NIKE" using both WP_QUERY and get_posts but it displays blank page

```
$args = array('post_type' => 'clothes','posts_per_page' => -1,
              'meta_query' => array(
                        array(
                                 'key' => 'storename',
                             'value' => 'NIKE',
                             'compare' => '='
                             )
                   )
              );
```

for wp_query i use

```
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
```

for get_posts i use

```
$loop=get_posts($args);
```

as soon as i put the line for `$loop` it returns blank page without the `$loop` th header etc is displayed. but not the content....just cant figure out how to display the content if both wp_query dont work...how to fix it.

when i change value from NIKE to something else say AMAZON it works fine. I can understand why its blocking particular value queries

Comment: Are you sure your script finishes excecution? It may be useful to turn on debug mode and check errors/logs.

Comment: i added error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1'); but still blank page

Comment: when i change value from NIKE to something else say AMAZON it works fine

Comment: blank page or blank results ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to inscrease memory limit

Open wp-config.php

Place this code at very top of file.

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '256M');
```

Comment: Can you tell me, why `memory_limit` is related to blank page?